# Get all tags used by a Shopify shop in one request

Tags: oauth, shopify, basic-authentication, shopify-app

When I try this URL in my browser:

```
https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/products/tags.json
```

It gives me a nice list of all the tags in my shop.

I need this list, but when I try an API call with Python it says 'Not found'. Since I can do it with my browser, there must be a way to do it programmatically.

Getting all the tags by looping over all products is too long (+- 5-10 seconds), whereas this gives me everything I need instantly.

How can I make this request?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The tags aren't exposed via the REST API, but they're accessible via the GraphQL Admin API:

```
{
  shop{
    productTags(first: 100){
      edges{
        node
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check [this](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-07/queries/productTags) for extra info

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I don't think this answer provides ALL tags, as you can't get all in one request and paging is not supported by API as well

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Shopify Rest API still doesn't have an endpoint to get all tags, vendors, types. And GraphQL Admin API can only get at maximum first 250 results.

You can get all of them through Shopify liquid ( Not working with the passworded store ).

1. Create a new search template name: search.foo.liquid

```
{% layout none %}
{
    "vendors" : {{shop.vendors|json}},
    "types" : {{shop.types|json}},
    "tags" : {% capture output %}
        {% for collection in collections %} 
                {% if forloop.index == 1 %}""{% endif %}
                {% if collection.all_tags.size > 0 %}
                    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
                        {% if output contains tag %}
                        {% else %}
                            ,"{{tag}}"
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}  
                {% endif %}     
        {% endfor %}
    {% endcapture %}
    {{ output | strip_newlines | prepend: '[' | append: ']' }}
}
```

2. Access: https://your-store.myshopify.com/search.json?view=foo in browser to view the result, Use cURL to get it in your application.